# Jquery scroll effects slows down the more it is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I am trying to create a box to just scroll up and down through a list of items by clicking an up or down arrow but the more I click on the up or down arrow not even very fast it just increasingly slows down the responsiveness of the scroll animation I have read some thing about it being recursively called which would I think would increase the responsiveness of the scroll effect. I am hoping some would could look at my jquery and give me some tips on improving the performance.

```
 $(window).load(function () {
        $("#ScrollUp_Wrapper").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#ScrollUp_Button").fadeIn("fast", function () {
                $(this).css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F2F2F2', endColorstr='#E5E5E5')"),
                $(this).css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F2F2F2), to(#E5E5E5))"),
                $(this).css("background", "-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #F2F2F2 , #E5E5E5)")
                $("#ScrollUp_Button").mouseup(function () {
                    $("#AllPost_leftcol").animate({ scrollTop: $("#AllPost_leftcol").scrollTop() - 200 }, 500);
                        });
                });
            }).mouseleave(function () {$("#ScrollUp_Button").fadeOut("fast");});


        $("#ScrollDown_Wrapper").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#ScrollDown_Button").fadeIn("fast", function () {
                    $(this).css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F2F2F2', endColorstr='#E5E5E5')"),
                    $(this).css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F2F2F2), to(#E5E5E5))"),
                    $(this).css("background", "-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #F2F2F2 , #E5E5E5)")
                    $("#ScrollDown_Button").mouseup(function () {
                        $("#AllPost_leftcol").animate({ scrollTop: $("#AllPost_leftcol").scrollTop() + 200 }, 500);
                    });
                   });
            }).mouseleave(function () {$("#ScrollDown_Button").fadeOut("fast");
        });

        });
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example?

Comment: `Jquery scroll effects slows down the more it is clicked`..I don't see a click event bound anywhere. A jsFiddle demonstrating the issue might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#ScrollUp_Button").off('mouseup').mouseup(function () {...}
```

And the same for ScrollDown button.

In your original code, each time mouse enter wrapper, you are handling a new click event for respective button.

Comment: I used the stop on everything except the scroll causes it was causing inconsistent scroll easing but it didn't fix the problem fully but the .off seems to have done the trick so thank u I don't have enough rep to vote up. I was trying put it in jsfiddle but the scroll functionality seems to not want to work in there I am not sure why I ran the syntax checker and it seemed to be clear here is the link if you want to check it out but it seems to have done the trick. Link http://jsfiddle.net/RMEsh/12/

Answer (score 0):

try to call [$.stop()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop#clearQueuegotoEnd) before queuing each next animation step:

```
$("#ScrollUp_Button").stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast", function () {
...
$("#AllPost_leftcol").stop(true, true).animate({ scrollTop: $("#AllPost_leftcol").scrollTop() - 200 }, 500);
...
$("#ScrollUp_Button").stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
...
```